# Why does Istanbul / tap code coverage report a switch statement as not covered when each conditional path is covered?

Tags: javascript, node.js, code-coverage, istanbul

In a node.js application I have a class with a getter that contains a large switch statement, same as this but larger with unreleased-product-specific values instead of a, b, c, 1, 2, 3 etc:

```
Class SomeClass () {
  constructor (someVar) {
    this.someProp = someVar
  }
  get someGetter () {
    switch (this.someProp) {
      case 'a':
      case 'b':
        return 1

      case 'c':
      case 'd':
      case 'e':
        return 2

      case 'f':
        return 3

      case undefined:
        return null

      default:
        return 0
    }
  }
}
```

I then have a test case structured like this, that reaches each of the possible paths:

```
const expectedResults = new Map(Object.entries({
  a: 1,
  c: 2,
  f: 3,
  null: null,
  z: 0
}))

for (const [testCase, expected] of expectedResults) {
  const someInstance = new SomeClass(testCase)
  t.equal(someInstance.someGetter, expected)
}

t.end()
```

This gave me coverage on all of the possible paths and no red flags in the [node tap](https://github.com/tapjs/node-tap) coverage report.

Hover, I get one (yellow) uncovered line, which is the line of the switch statement itself: line 6 in the example code, the line:

```
switch (this.someProp) {
```

I've tried adding redundant `break`s after each `return`, but these are then (correctly!) flagged as uncovered (because they're unreachable).

I thought maybe it's complaining because it has a test for, for example, `'a'` in the path that returns `1` but not `'b'` in the same path. But if that's the problem I don't understand why it's flagging the switch statement itself, not those specific lines.

Comment: What's the question? And you already have the answer? Are you asking something here?

Comment: I've edited the title to be a grammatical question. And it's encouraged to post answers to your own questions if you have them: it shares knowledge with other people searching on the same problem in future, while keeping open the possibility of someone posting an even better answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The uncovered line notice disappeared when I had the tests cover every possible `case:`, not just every path.

Since there were many, many cases in my real world code, and all of the return paths are tested as being correct, rather than extending the `expectedResults` map massively, I created another, simpler test condition which took a simple array of every case and simply made sure that each one was recognised (wasn't falling back to the default value). Like:

```
const allCases = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

for (const testCase of allCases) {
  const someInstance = new SomeClass(testCase)
  t.notEqual(someInstance.someGetter, 0)
}
```

By comparing against the default fallback value, there's at least some value to this test, it's not purely there to meet 100% coverage: it makes sure no possible cases in the switch get deleted in future etc (e.g. if the switch statement is reordered or modified).